# jQuery show content in DIV

Tags: jquery

How can I make the following code work? thanks

```
<span onclick="showim('<h1>Test Head 1</h1><h2>Test Head 2</h2>');">Test</span>
<div id="divcont"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.showim = function(src) {
        $("divcont").html(src);
    };
});
```

Comment: id-selector `$("#divcont").html(src);` - missing `#` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UVQq9/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            window.showim = function(src) {
                $("#divcont").html(src);
            };
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't notice that #